# Preventing div scrolling back to top when changing position to fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div containing a list of photo names. When a name is clicked, another div (outside the first one) is displayed with the photo and comments below it. When this second div is scrolled (using the main window scrollbar), I do not want the first div to scroll along, it should remain where it is. So, as soon as I open the photo div, I change the first div's position from **absolute** to **fixed**. So far so good, this works fine.

However, when the first div has been scrolled before a photo is opened, the setting of this div to fixed, causes it to jump back to the top, while I want it to remain where it was. Is there a way to do this? Why does it jump to the top?

Basically I want to achieve the same as showing photo's in Facebook. The background is frozen where it is while the photo area can be scrolled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fixed div jumps to the top because having no top/bottom values basically means they're positioned at 0.

Now, to prevent this you will have to set the current position (before `position` is changed to `fixed`) *in relation to the window* (that's the key part).

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZX5h/25/)

The jquery part from that:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    var ftop = $('#fixer').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var fleft = $('#fixer').offset().left;
    $('#fixer').css({position: 'fixed', left: fleft + 'px', top: ftop + 'px'});
});
```

Before the position is fixed, the current top coordinates [`offset().top - (window).scrollTop`] are calculated and then passed to the `#fixer`'s `top` value. The `$(window).scrollTop()` is important because it makes sure the `#fixer` will always be at viewpoint when fixed.