# changing div to fixed and back for lightbox

Tags: jquery, css

I have an html file

```
<html>
<body>
<div #main> <a click to open lightbox> <img> <more images> </a> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the lightbox opens, This becomes

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <div id="main"> <a click to open lightbox> <img> <more images> </a> </div>
    <div id="pic_holder">...Popup div content </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want #main to be noscroll. I read about overflow:hidden, and position:static; etc. My css `.noscroll{}`.

The problem is, if I use overflow:hidden on #main for noscroll, body still scrolls. If I use position:static on #main, after pop up is closed, #body scrolls to top. The idea is to get pinterest like behaviour, and I am using prettyphoto.

Appreciate any hints. Somewhat related to [Preventing div scrolling back to top when changing position to fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492824/preventing-div-scrolling-back-to-top-when-changing-position-to-fixed?rq=1) but it does not talk about a light box being added. and thats where the problem is.

Comment: jQuery code or a live example would be very helpful.

Comment: @Fresheyeball a bit long script. how can I share it? its on my local machine.

Comment: Create a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) (using the least amount of code possible) on Jsfiddle

Comment: @aVC or you could share your local IP address ( you can always change it later )

Comment: @Fresheyeball click on the image that is like a hand. the second image. I have lightbox only on that image.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Objective is, when the image is clicked, #main should be noscroll at the position where it is, and pop up light box should be scrollable if overflowing. When pop up is closed, #main should resume scrollable as normal

Comment: @aVC right now your <body> is scrolling, what you need is an additional layer to control this. I am heading out right now, but later today I should have time to write down how to fix this with more clarity.

Comment: Basically write a script to insure that #main is the same size as the window at all times, and on resize. Then inside main wrap everything in another div called #mainInner. This way you can change main from overflow auto to overflow hidden and back without moving the window position.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Thanks, kirkas gave some hints which I am trying now. But I will wait for your approach when you get the thance. Thx

Comment: @aVC you might also want to try something like onscroll return false, or onscroll e.preventDefault, but that's a tad hacky.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Thanks, wanted to tell you that I got it working (credit to kirkas). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need code for better answer, here some tip-off

1. Have you tried to set your body on "overflow:hidden"?
2. The scroll depend on which element you're hovering, have you tried to set your #main size to the window size?

Salutations

[update]

After i've seen your website here some change i think you should do.

1. Make the "pp_pic_holder" child of the "pp_overlay".
2. place your "pp_pic_holder" in css, not fixed, use "margin: 0 auto;"
3. In Jquery, use "resize" function on windows to set the width/height of your "pp_overlay" to the window one. It should look like this.

   ```
   function overlayResize(){
      var WW=$(window).width();
      var WH=$(window).height();
      $(".overlay").height(WH).width(WW);
   }


   $(window).resize(function(){
       overlayResize();
   })

   overlayResize();
   ```

Here some jsFiddle is did:

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkas/PSjTD/

[update]
And if you want to scroll in the overlay, don't forget to add:

```
    overflow:auto;
```

to your overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkas/PSjTD/

[Update]

This one make the stop hiding function when you click in the selected pics.

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkas/PSjTD/

Comment: yes, I tried overflow:hidden. If I use it on #main, the whole body still scrolls. If I use it on body, the pop up overflow also goes hidden. I did not set #main size to window size, because, it is less than window size. I posted the url. do you need me to send the code?

Comment: Thanks. but the problem is if you change your .selectedPic{} height to say 700px; then the popup extends below the viewport, but cannot be scrolled.

Comment: set "overflow:auto;" on the overlay

Comment: Cool. it looks good on the fiddle. let me try on the actual. Appreciate it very much and will let you know soon.

Comment: Don't forget to make the "pp_pic" holder child of the "pp_overlay" if you don't you can't scroll in the overlay.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Not completely good news. I cannot get the scroll on the overlay+popup. Also, for some reason, the pop now is transparent. www.avarachan.com/test2/Texample/index.html

Comment: That because your overlay isn't resizing to the window size.. and the opacity is probably because you set it by animate the opacity, instead of using RGBa in css.

Comment: I was nt confident enough to make that much changes into the script. Is there a workaround? or should I change it to rgba?

Comment: If you change opacity, it will change the whole element, including the children, but with RGBa on "background" in css affect only the selected element background (more logical & pratical)

Comment: I fixed the scroll issue. you were right, overlayresize was not properly called. now it is working. the opacity thing is deep in code, let me see if i can understand it and change it to rgb, though the opacity feature was more desirable.

Comment: check out this: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Comment: wonderful.  i just saw that you have a 4th element in rgb which is opacity. And that solves all, Thanks a lot. spent 3 days on this. :)